# Bootstrap Angular Datepicker format is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I am using datepicker directive for my angular application. I am trying to set the format in text box as in the format 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY' i.e `Mon, 14 Mar 2016`.

I have changed it in my code as
`uib-datepicker-popup="ddd, dd MMM yyyy"`but this displays date format as `ddd, 14 Mar 2016`.
How can I get the day of the week also printed with date in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
uib-datepicker-popup="EEE, dd MMM yyyy"
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try `"D, dd MMM yyyy"`

For more date format options you can check here -[Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php%22Date%22)